# Delete specific string from array column python dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm trying to remove string '$A' from column a array elements.
But below code doesn't seems to work.
In the below code I'm trying to replace $A string with empty string (it doesn't work though) also, instead I would like to just delete that string.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [['$A','1'], ['$A', '3','$A'],[]], 'b': ['4', '5', '6']})

df['a'] = df['a'].replace({'$A': ''}, regex=True)
print(df['a'])
```

Answer (score 3):

`replace` doesn't check inside the list element, you'll have to use loops/apply in this case:

```
df['a'] = df.a.apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if s != '$A'])

df
#     a  b
#0  [1]  4
#1  [3]  5
#2   []  6
```